# Rename "orders and returns" link in the footer

Tags: magento

I want to rename the "orders and returns" link in the magento footer to something more meaningful. How could I do this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I spend about an hour or two looking through the files trying to track down the source of the text. I cant tell you exactly what i've tried becuase i must have searched through a hundred files. i also tried editing the mage_sales.csv file

Comment: If you have any questions about the site then please see our [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) or visit [meta] and post a question there. Thanks.

Comment: No i dont have any questions about the site; And (presuming that it was you who deleted my comment) I don't appreciate my comment about the FAQ being deleted being followed with another suggestion that I read it. If you want to delete my posts then i cant do anything about that but making the antithesis of the very point I was making is rude if you ask me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file in question is app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Guest/Links.php, the protected $_label attribute to be accurate. Of course you should overload the block rather than change the core file.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfect. Sorry, am new to magento, by overload the block do you mean put the edited copy of links.php into app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Block/Guest/ ?

Comment: That is the most basic option, and probably better than editing the core file. The 'correct' way is to rewrite the class, which you can find by searching for something like 'Magento Block rewrite'. However it is an extremely simple class you are editing, depending on the situation it's up to you if you think it's worth the effort.